# Excepción cuando hago el parse dentro de mi `jButton2ActionPerformed`

Tags: java

Quiero agregar en la columna "descripción" de mi jTable el texto seteado en mi jButton2, pero si se repite dicha información, en la fila correspondiente sumar 1 mas en la columna "cant".

Al realizar el parse `String val = (String)TabVentas.getValueAt(i, 0);` me tira una excepción, por lo cual no me estoy dando cuenta que error estoy cometiendo.

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0`

Ademas cuando hago `TabVentas.setValueAt(/*...*/, i, 1);` estoy queriendo sumar 1+ a la columna correspondiente del campo "cant" pero noce como hacerlo.

```
package elbuengusto;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class NuevaVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultTableModel mt4;


    public NuevaVenta() {
        initComponents();

        Date fecha = new Date(); //fecha y hora actual
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //formatear la fecha en una cadena
        FechaAc.setText(sdf.format(fecha)); //setear la representacion en cadena de la fech

         //tabVentas

         String titulos4 [] = {"Descripcion","Cant" };// creando la tabla a gusto
         String filas4 [][] = {};

         mt4 = new DefaultTableModel(filas4, titulos4);

         TableColumnModel colVentas = TabVentas.getColumnModel(); //para poder modificar los anchos de las columnas

         TabVentas.setModel(mt4);// para poder mostrar la tabla
         //para que te tome la modificacion del tamanio tenes que hacerlo despues de mostrar la tabla
         colVentas.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(55);
         colVentas.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300);

    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      int i = 0; 
      String[] fila = {jButton2.getText()};
      String val = (String)TabVentas.getValueAt(i, 0);**//excepción** 

      while(val != null){

        if(val == jButton2.getText())

           TabVentas.setValueAt(/*...*/, i, 1);

        i++;
        val = (String)TabVentas.getValueAt(i, 0);
      }

      mt4.addRow(fila);
    }
```

Comment: "me tira una excepción"... podrías adjuntar por favor que excepción "te tira"?

Comment: si... pero que excepción es? NullFormatException?

Comment: amigo, solo necesitaba esta linea `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0`

Comment: Gracias! estoy aprendiendo a usar netbeans.

Comment: Este puede ser uno de los errores String filas4 [][] = {}; y despues hace un get sobre el de alguna manera es como hacer esto filas4[0][0]; y obtiene una Exception. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la excepción que agregaste:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

Estas tratando de acceder a la posición de un array mas allá de su límite.

```
String filas4 [][] = {}; // Las filas están vacías en tu código.
```

En este caso estas intentando acceder a posiciones de tu tabla que no existen, por ejemplo a la posición 0 de las filas. Asegúrate de agregar filas, considera este código de ejemplo:

```
Object[][]rows = new Object[ ][ ] { {"a","b"} , {"c","d"} }; 
Object[]columns = new Object[] {"column1","column2"}; 
JTable table = new JTable(); 
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rows,columns));
```

Acá hay una respuesta a tu pregunta en inglés que también te puede servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732503/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-0-0-attempting-to-populate-jtable

Comment: Gracias Hector, entiendo el problema! te lo agradezco!